# Cannot locate compiled CSS of Less CSS Maven plugin

Tags: maven, less, maven-plugin

I am totally new to Apache Maven and LessCSS. So I tried to include the Less compiler plugin like described at https://github.com/marceloverdijk/lesscss-maven-plugin. No problems so far, all files get compiled well and css file is created in `/target/[project name]/css` folder.

Than I tried to include the created *.css file, but I have no idea which path I should set. Where does Maven put down the builded files?

After build, the `/target/[project name]/` folder does only contain the new css folder. But I can access my application on localhost without any errors, except the missing css.

**CSS Include:**

```xml
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

**POM.xml**

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>holidayplanner</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Maven complier plugin that forces maven to use specified version of JDK/JRE while compilation -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Less CSS Plugin -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.lesscss</groupId>
            <artifactId>lesscss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${less.css.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/less</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/css</outputDirectory>
                <compress>true</compress>
                <includes>
                    <include>main.less</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

**Update:** 
After setting the `<force>` property to true, I can see the compiled css file under `appName.war/css/main.css`.
But I still cannot access my css file.

Tomcat7 Error: "The requested resource is not available."

Spring ResourceHandler:

```xml
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("/webjars/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/img/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/less/**").addResourceLocations("/less/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/pages/");
}
```

Spring Security:

```xml
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
            .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/webjars/**","/css/**", "/less/**","/img/**","/js/**");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe no LessCSS sources changed since last build?  By default, the Plugin skips un-modified sources.

To force the plugin to compile all sources regardless of modified timestamps, add a force node into your plugin config:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <force>true</force>
    ...
</configuration>
```

NOTE: I've seen build logs from the compiler still saying sources were "bypassed", but with the force config node in place the css does get compiled, so don't just check the log -- check the target folder to find your css output.

Hope this helps!

Tze